# Finding interval of convergence for $\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty k!(x-4)^k$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I'm trying to find the interval of convergence for the series... 
$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty k!(x-4)^k$$
I found that $$\lim_{k\to\infty}\left|\frac{(k+1)!(x-4)^{k+1}}{k!(x-4)^{k}}\right|=\infty$$ which as far as I understand would mean the interval of convergence is 0, is my limit wrong?

Answer (score 3):

No, it is perfectly fine. That means your series converges *only* for $x=4$. Observe that if $x=4$, you limit is $0$, not $\infty$! In *any* other case, it is $\infty$, so your series converges only at one point.

As it was mentioned in comments, the **interval** or domain of convergence is the *singleton* $\{4\}$ (a set of elements) whereas the **radius** of convergence is $0$.

Comment: Strictly speaking, the "interval" of convergence is the singleton $\{4\}$.  The _radius_ of convergence is $0$.